# Parsing SOAP response using NSXMLParser with Swift

Tags: web-services, swift, soap, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse the Soap response (snippet shown below) using NSXMLParser. However when I print the Element names in the didStartElemnt delegate method I only get the following elements returned.

Element's name is soap:Envelope

Element's name is soap:Body

Element's name is SearchResponse

Element's name is SearchResult

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <SearchResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
   <SearchResult><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Results xmlns="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/SearchResult" xmlns:gms="http://www.def.ghi.uk/CM/gms" xmlns:n2=" (more here + further elements....)
```

Why do I not see the Results (or any subsequent) element?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the second `<?xml . . .>` directive that appears inside the `<SearchResult>`. That directive is only allowed at the start of an xml file.

Comment: I guessed it might have something to do with that. Any suggestions as to how I might resolve the issue?

Comment: Ideally, you would remove it on the server side. If that's not possible, then the brute force way to do it is to remove the offending directive from the string before you parse.